# Use checkboxes to retrieve information from table

Tags: php, mysql

I am using checkboxes to store products in table column named products. They are all stored in cell and separated by comma. 
Now I am trying to retrieve information from the table. If I check more products it will display all users that have products. All user products are saved in one cell and separated with comma for ex products(10,50,90,160)

```
html code
<input type="checkbox" name="proizvodi[]" value="10"><b>product1<b/> <br/> <br/>
<input type="checkbox" name="proizvodi[]" value="50"><b>product2<b/> <br/> <hr/>
<input type="checkbox" name="proizvodi[]" value="100"><b>product3</b> <br/>
<input type="checkbox" name="proizvodi[]" value="150"><b>product4</b> <br/>

php code
$variable=$_POST['proizvodi'];

print_r($_POST['proizvodi']);

var_dump ($variable); 

$upit= "SELECT * FROM `clanovi` WHERE FIND_IN_SET($variable[0],PROIZVODI)"; 

if(sizeof($variable)>1)
{
        for($i=1; $i<sizeof($variable); $i++)
        {
        $upit.=" OR FIND_IN_SET($variable[$i],PROIZVODI) ";
        }
}
print($upit);
$result=mysqli_query($con,$upit);

var_dump($upit);
?>
<?
    echo "<table border='5'>
    <tr>
    <th> </th>
    <th>ID</th>
    <th>NAZIV</th>
    <th>ADRESA</th>
    <th>DRZAVA</th>
    <th>GRAD</th>
    <th>EMAIL</th>
    <th>WEB</th>
    <th>TEL </th>
    <th>KONTAKT </th>
    <th>MOBITEL </th>
    <th>PROIZVODI </th>
    </tr>";

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
    {

    echo "<tr>";
    echo '<td><input type="checkbox" name="ticked[]" value="' . $row['EMAIL'] . '"></td>';
    echo "<td>" . $row['ID'] . "</td>"; 
    echo "<td>" . $row['NAZIV'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['ADRESA'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['DRZAVA'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['GRAD'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['EMAIL'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['WEB'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['TEL1'] . "</td>"; 
    echo "<td>" . $row['KONTAKT-OSOBA'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['MOBITEL'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['PROIZVODI'] . "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
    }
    echo "</table>";
```

//PRINT RESULT

```
Array ( [0] => 10 [1] => 50 [2] => 100 [3] => 101 )

array
  0 => string '10' (length=2)
  1 => string '50' (length=2)
  2 => string '100' (length=3)
  3 => string '101' (length=3)

SELECT * FROM `clanovi` WHERE FIND_IN_SET(10,PROIZVODI) OR FIND_IN_SET(50,PROIZVODI) OR FIND_IN_SET(100,PROIZVODI) OR FIND_IN_SET(101,PROIZVODI)
```

I think the problem occurs here because more values are stored in one cell and separated with , .. and i look always for specific value in the cell

Any help or advice is appreciated

Comment: Did you try searching the site for similar questions?

Comment: Yes i did could not find similar answer that could be of help.

Comment: We'r getting too many "comma separated values in a cell" questions these days (think). As @GordonM said, there are many such questions on SO and many of them have best answer, "redesign your database the correct way"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Mysql's FIND_INSET Function for each posted `proizvodi` values(i.e. use `foreach`)

```
SELECT FIND_IN_SET('a','a,b,c');
```

e.g.,

**proizvodi** field has two rows (10,11,12,13) and 11,12,13,22

The following code should work

```
<?php

$variable=array(11,13);

$upit= "SELECT * FROM `clanovi` WHERE FIND_IN_SET($variable[0],proizvodi)";

if(sizeof($variable)>1)
{
    for($i=1; $i<sizeof($variable); $i++)
    {
        $upit.=" OR FIND_IN_SET($variable[$i],proizvodi) ";
}
}
echo $upit;
echo "<br />";
$result=mysqli_query($con,$upit);
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
echo "<pre>";
print_r($row);
}


//
?>
```

The above code will output

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [id] => 1
    [1] => 10,11,12,13
    [proizvodi] => 10,11,12,13
)

Array
(
    [0] => 2
    [id] => 2
    [1] => 11,12,13,22
    [proizvodi] => 11,12,13,22
)


$variable=array(11,13);//here I hard coded but it will be posted data(checkboxes value)
```

[image]

Comment: I have tried but only works when checked value is stored first in cell. for example if chosen value is 10 and values stored in table are (15,18,10) it does not work, if values are stored (10,15,18,123) then it works and could find only one first value.

Comment: I have posted. Thanks for helping

Comment: its working here FIND_IN_SET doesn't depend whether its first value or anywhere other than first

Comment: Print your query and check from phpmyadmin. modify accordingly

Comment: I have tried and still the same happens even if I check in phpmyadmin. WHen I print query it looks SELECT * FROM `clanovi` WHERE FIND_IN_SET(50,PROIZVODI) OR FIND_IN_SET(100,PROIZVODI) OR FIND_IN_SET(101,PROIZVODI) OR FIND_IN_SET(102,PROIZVODI) and in this case value 100 is first value in one row and I got results, value 102 is not at the placed on first place it does not print it.

Comment: PROVIDE $variable(posted) AS  array and column(proizvodi) values

Comment: I am new in programming could you please be more specific or write what you mean. Thanks

Comment: I have seen still not able to fix it. I have updated the whole php file

Answer (score 0):

Use FIND_IN_SET string function of MySQL like this

```
SELECT * FROM `clanovi` WHERE 
FIND_IN_SET($variable[1],PROIZVODI) > 0 AND 
FIND_IN_SET($variable[2],PROIZVODI) > 0 ...
```

Read more: [MySQL Reference](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set)

Comment: I have tried, it does not work. But I have found solution. Thanks for post

Answer (score 0):

This code works for my case. Iam posting in case someone else have the same problem in future

```
$variable=$_POST['proizvodi'];

print_r($variable);

var_dump ($variable); 
//SELECT * FROM CLANOVI WHERE OR PROIZVODI LIKE '%50%';

$upit= "SELECT * FROM `clanovi` WHERE PROIZVODI LIKE '%$variable[0]%'"; 

if(sizeof($variable)>1)
{
        for($i=1; $i<sizeof($variable); $i++)
        {
            $upit.=" OR PROIZVODI LIKE '%$variable[$i]%' ";
        }
}
```

I am using implode function to store products and then I am using checkboxes again to retrieve data. FIND_IN_SET function does not work it shows only firs value.

Answer (score -1):

use like 
for ex "SELECT * FROM `clanovi` WHERE PROIZVODI LIKE '%$variable[0]%'"

Comment: really? what about 10,11,12.  your query will match these all values